# Using Params hash in my Rails App

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So what I am trying to do is generate a list of breweries based on a location that the user enters into an input field. How I have it set up is in my javascript I have the browser send ajax requests to the server, the server then communicates with a 3rd party's database and back to the browser.

This code works when I hardcode a location like "Chicago" in the controller but I want to generalize it so I can pass in whatever location the user inputted. I think this has something to do with the params hash but am uncertain as to how to implement.

routes.rb

```
get 'search' => 'home#search_breweries_by_location'
```

home controller.rb

```
def search_breweries_by_location
  breweries = @brewery_db.locations.all(locality: location)
  render({:json=>breweries})
end
```

/home/index.html.erb

```
var location = document.getElementById('location').value;

$.post('/search', {locality: location}, function(data){
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    $('#brewery-list').append(data[i].brewery.name);
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you see in the log files if you add `Rails.logger.info "\nParams Hash: #{params.inspect}\n"` at the top of the `search_breweries_by_location` method in your `home_controller.rb`?

Comment: Hmm... dont know how to acess log file

Comment: Assuming you're in your app's directory, in Terminal:  `tail -f log/development.log`

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with log files etc.. so far console is saying this: Started GET "/search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-13 15:34:36 -0500
Processing by HomeController#search_breweries_by_location as */*
Completed 200 OK in 780ms (Views: 62.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sort of new to Rails myself, but I've always used the following paradigm to look things up in ActiveRecord:

```
@brewery_db.locations.where(locality: params[:locality])
```

Again not sure if this solves your issue, but maybe the `params[:locality]` part will get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

One of your issues is that you are making a `POST` to `/search` but you only have a route that matches `GET` on `/search`.  I would start by switching your route to match on `POST` instead of `GET`.